# `Count Distinct` and `Group By` produce weird results

Tags: mysql, sql, count, group-by, distinct

Please consider the following query:

```
SELECT artist.id, COUNT(DISTINCT artist$styles.v_id)
FROM artist
LEFT JOIN artist$styles ON artist$styles.p_id = artist.id
```

This is the result I get:

```
id  count
1   4
```

The questions are:

1. How come it's only selecting one row from the `artist` table, when there are 4 rows in it and there are no `WHERE`, `HAVING`, `LIMIT` or `GROUP BY` clauses applied to the query?
2. There are only three records in `artist$styles` having `p_id` of value `1`, why is it counting `4`?
3. Why if I add a `GROUP BY` clause to it I get the correct results?

   ```
   SELECT artist.id, COUNT(DISTINCT artist$styles.v_id)
   FROM artist
   LEFT JOIN artist$styles ON artist$styles.p_id = artist.id
   GROUP BY artist.id
   ----
   id  count
   1   3
   2   1
   3   3
   4   1
   ```
4. This all just doesn't make sense to me. Could this be a bug of MySQL? I'm running Community 5.5.25a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. As stated in [the manual page on aggregate functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-functions.html) (of which `COUNT()` is one):

   > If you use a group function in a statement containing no `GROUP BY` clause, it is equivalent to grouping on all rows.
2. As stated in [the manual page on `GROUP BY` with hidden columns](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html):

   > The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate.

   In other words, the server has chosen one (indeterminate) value for column `p_id`, which happens in this case to be the value `1`, whilst it has properly aggregated and counted the result for the `COUNT()` function.
3. Because you are then grouping on the correct columns, rather than on all rows.
4. It's not a bug; this behaviour is documented and by design.

Comment: On point 4, don't you think it will lead to confusion if one of the columns is omitted by mistake in Group by clause. All MySQL developers find it difficult to debug the code for all these so called "behaviour". IMO, it is a bug.

Comment: @Madhivanan: By the definition of a 'bug' being unintended behaviour, how can documented behaviour ever be a bug?

Comment: Using this documented behaviour, developers find it difficult when they omit column names by mistake. There are so many exmaples like these . Like WHERE col will return all rows although column value is omitted. As ANSI SQL Standard all non aggreate columns should be part of GROUP BY Clause

Comment: @Madhivanan: There are lots of documented behaviours in lots of different products that developers misunderstand or find difficult.  But that doesn't mean those behaviours are a 'bug'.  I don't disagree that it might have been better had the MySQL developers made other design decisions, but it was their conscious intended decision to introduce these behaviours by design and therefore they cannot be considered a 'bug'.

Comment: @eggyal, those who come from other RDBMs background are suffered mostly. But I would really like to see MySQL not to include these in future releases.

Comment: @Madhivanan: That you wish for MySQL to be designed differently does not make the existing design a 'bug'.  Anyway, this is verging on FUD. Thank you for your comments.

Comment: Thanks @eggyal for your valuable time on commenting on my comments :)

Comment: @Madhivanan Turns out, this behaviour is not specific to MySQL. I've just tested it on SqLite - the results are the same

Answer (score 0):

It is a possible bug in Mysql. All non aggeregate columns should be included in Group by clause. MySQL does not force this and the result is unpredictable and hard to debug. As a rule always include all non-aggregate columns in the Group by clause. This is how all RDBMSs work

Answer (score 0):

1. Count Function return single row result if you are not using group by clause and that's why its returning one row.

2.In your output

```
id  count
1   4
```

4 is total no of results in that table not result for id 1.and it display in front of 1 because only one row produce.

3.when you use group by then a group of that column value is created that's why you get that output.

And finally its not a bug.Mysql provide a proper documentation for that you can read on mysql site.